# What does it mean !{0}, !{1}, !{2} ... on zsh in Ubuntu?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, zsh

Recently, I accidentally typed `!{0}`. I think it is some kind of special zsh function because it showed one of my previous commands while I execute it.

What does it mean on zsh?

```
$ !{0}
```

Note: I'm using zsh on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're "using `zsh` on ubuntu" then you are not using `bash`. `bash` and `zsh` are two different shells, which have slightly different behaviours.

In both shells, `!` introduces a history expansion, which replaces the `!` and following word with something taken from the command history.

In `zsh`, `!{0}` will be replaced with the previous command you typed which started with <kbd>0</kbd>; the same as `!0`. In bash, the braces are treated literally, so `!{0}` will be replaced with the previous command which started with <kbd>{</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>. In both shells, `!1` will be replaced with the first command in the history (if it is still remembered); in `zsh`, `!{1}` will also be replaced with the first command in the history, while in `bash` it will be replaced by a command starting with <kbd>{</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>

Comment: oops. Thanks for the information. I will fix the question. change bash to zsh.